# Proof of uniqueness and existence theorem for first order ordinary differential equations

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have a first order ODE of the form $y^\prime = f(x,y)$ with initial conditions $y(x_0) = y_0$. The existence and uniqueness theorem states that if $f$ and its partial derivative with respect to $y$ are continuous in some rectangular region $\{(x, y); |x - x_0| \leqslant a,|y - y_0| \leqslant b\}$ then there exists a unique solution of the ODE in the closed interval $[x_0 - h, x_0 + h]$ where $h < a$. 
I am familiar with the above definition and the various linked topics, such as Picard Iterations, Leibniz integral rule etc but was wondering if anyone could provide a proof of this theorem.

Comment: Is this about getting a local Lipschitz constant from a bound of $f_y$?

Comment: Well I was just after a quick-ish proof (if there is one!)

Comment: Does the knowledge of Picard iterations extend to the theorem of Picard-Lindelöf?

Comment: I second that. You want the Picard-Lindelöf theorem.

Comment: Yes it does. Would anyone be willing to provide a proof of the theorem based on Picard-Lindelöf?

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental theorem tells you that
$$
f(x,y)-f(x,z)=\int_{[y,z]}f_ydy=\int_0^1f_y(x,y+t(z-y))·(z-y)\,dt.
$$

The region $\{(x,y);|x−x_0|⩽a,\|y−y_0\|⩽b\}$ is a compact set, $f_y$ is continuous thus bounded, let $L$ be a bound. Then
$$
\|f(x,y)-f(x,z)\|\le\int_0^1L·\|z-y\|\,dt=L·\|z-y\|
$$
which provides the Lipschitz condition on $f$. Now apply Picard-Lindelöf.

Comment: Bu why specifically is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ a requirement for Picard-Lindelöf?

Comment: *that should read: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is continuous

Comment: Sorry, just seen it in your response.

Comment: Could you please explain where the second integral on the first line comes from? It appears to be a substitution.

Comment: The first is a line integral over the segment $[y,z]$. Parametrizing the segment as $\gamma(t)=y+t(z-y)$, $t\in[0,1]$ gives the second integral.